# Sending email from Salesforce through mass email appears in a Junk folder

Tags: email, massemailmessage

I sent survey email to my customer through Salesforce mass email function but I get only few responses back. When I called to some Customer they said the did not receive any survey email then they checked and email was in their Junk folder.
Is there any way we can send email direct in Inbox and email should not go in junk folder.

Please suggest.

Comment: You can check this post for some info https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hgDgAAI

Comment: Above link advise me to use email relay. Do you think it will work?

Answer (score 0):

If you end up in junk folder, be sure these basics are good:

- No capital letters in your subjectline
- Content that matches your subjectline
- Your sender score is good
- Your IP is warmed up
- Your recievers are among good openers and have given permission to recieving your mail.

I know these are basics, but sometimes these are so simple, that they're actually forgotten